# How do you remove "shared" status from a file in Visual Source Safe?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Currently, I am working on a file that is shared between multiple projects in Visual Source Safe and we have come to a point where we need to update it to be specific to a certain project. Is there a way to safely remove the shared status from the file file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a "branch files" icon in the toolbar. looks like a page on the left with two arrows split pointing right.

Go to the project that you need to roll-back to a prior version and branch at THAT instance.  Leave the PRIMARY entry alone.  Then, you should be able to do a roll-back of that specific single file (or files) as needed.

Comment: SourceSafe help for the branch command "Branches a previously shared file. The Visual SourceSafe Branch command breaks the shared link between copies of the file, making the file versions independent and able to be part of separate projects."